# Does Google App Engine support Spring 4 + JPA 2 + Hibernate + Cloud SQL (MySQL)?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, app-engine-flexible

I built a Spring 4 JPA application with Hibernate as the JPA vendor. I used JPARepository for accessing databases. It works totally fine when running locally on Jetty. However, it throws ' No qualifying bean ' exception for my custom repository classes when running on Google App Engine. Isn't JPA 2 supported on Google App Engine FLEXIBLE environment?